# When is a body at rest?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics, inertial-frames, mass-energy

I wonder when a particle is considered at rest. I'm aware that this is commonly given when all forces balance each other out.
I'm more interested how the rest energy $ E = mc^2 $ has to be understood respectively when it can be applied. As far as I know particles are never at rest so they will always move and oscillate a bit. In our everyday's world this does not matter but when observing single elementary particles, this should matter. It probably does and is probably also considered. I would like to know how and why doesn't the cited equation violate these circumstances?

Comment: when all forces balance the *acceleration* is $0$ but the body can have constant non-zero velocity and NOT be at rest in that particular frame of reference.

Comment: The full equation is $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(\mathbf{p}c)^2$, which takes motion into account.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's true, thanks. But nevertheless, an (elementary) particle usually doesn't move only in a single direction, e.g. in nuclei.

Comment: @G.Smith I know, that's why I want to know when $ E = mc^2 $ can be applied. Or rather why it can be applied.

Comment: Your formula can be applied in the "rest frame "of the particle, i.e. the reference frame in which the speed of the particle is zero (hence the one in which you are moving along with the particle).

Comment: That's absolutely right! :)

Comment: You have to specify a frame of reference when discussing rest or motion. You may be at rest sitting at your desk but there is someone else moving relative to you and in their frame of reference you are not at rest. So "at rest" just means not moving in whatever frame of reference is being considered. It is a relative, not an absolute, property of an object.

Answer (score 1):

[The relativistic mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass), defined by $E=mc^2$ is not the same as the [invariant  mass in](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)

[image]

The invariant  mass comes from the "length" of the four vector and is invariant to Lorenz transformations , it characterizes particles and systems of particles.

The $m$ in $E=mc^2$ is velocity dependent and the formula has fallen out of use in particle physics because of the misunderstandings it involves.

So a body is at rest in a frame  when $p=mv$ is zero , and it is called the center of mass system. There is always a Lorentz transformation to the center of mass system.

[Elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle)  are point particles, so their center of mass is the point defining them. But for any invariant mass of complex systems, a center of mass frame can be found.

(the relativistic mass is not useful in transformations between frames, as it is not invariant)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm surprised that the relativistic mass and the invariant mass is not the same. I think I understand that the concept behind is different but, as you quote it yourself, the mathematical equation just states it is the same? Or do I have to require $ m = m_0 $ ? Hence, your comment, that the formula is not used in particle physics anymore, relates to the relativistic mass?

Comment: Yes , the relativistic mass is not used in particle physics, because it is not an invariant under Lorentz transformations, it is velocity dependent.